# Can't run rxgraph on remote slave computer when connect to pr2

Tags: ros, rxgraph, multi-machine

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I connect to pr2 and set the ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_MASTER_URI, I can  and retrieve the list of currently running nodes. Besides, the simple node I wrote can execute successfully on my slave computer. I think these mean that the connection is correct. However, I just can't open rxgraph. The rxgraph window only show "initializing". Any suggestion? Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48674/can%27t-run-rxgraph-on-remote-slave-computer-when-connect-to-pr2/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you connect to your robot using ssh? Did you enable X-forwarding, i.e. `ssh -X`? You should also connect directly to the second computer, i.e. don't ssh from c1 to c2 if you want to have X forwarding enabled.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-21**:
How can I open a window when I ssh to the robot in the terminal? My current method is to use multi- machine and try to open rxgraph in the slave computer, but failed.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-21**:
With X-forwarding, you can run gui applications through ssh when you use X-forwarding. Please read the [support page](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) and be more specific. What did you set ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_MASTER_URI to and on which computers. Which errors did you get.

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-22**:
After connect my laptop to PR2's LAN, I type:(in laptop)

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.68.0.1:11311

export ROS_HOSTNAME=10.68.0.142(get from ifconfig)

And then I try to open rxgraph in my laptop, the window of rxgraph remains "initializing".

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-22**:
Don't set ROS_HOSTNAME but ROS_IP. I doubt that this is the cause of the problem though. Try `rosnode list` and try executing `rosnode info <node name>` on one of the listed nodes to verify that your network connection is really working.